# *.png file seems to increase in filesize without any change

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, resolution

I have to save my images as png-8, 300ppp, with Photoshop CS6 and always works good. But today, the same image yesterday was 250kb, today is 1.1MB, without making any change. Can somebody help me, please? I work on Mac.
[image: Yesterday]

[image: Today]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Eva! What do you mean "the same image yesterday was 250kb"? Because one of your images here says "copia", so it's a different file. Maybe the second one was saved in **PNG-24** instead of PNG-8?

Comment: Yisela, I can see the png-8 and png-24 if I save for web devices, but if I save from the File - Save and select the png option, how can I know the png-number? 
EDIT: I take off the copy option and just go down 0.1MB :(

Comment: The two images you posted don't seem to be the ones that are described:J2kcw.png is 67018 bytes 454x346,  and F1276.png is 54590 bytes, 475x294.  So, if they are actually scaled-down copies of your two images, it's not easy to diagnose the problem.  Can you post the actual problematic images?

Comment: Glen, yes I can, but they are huge and I don't know if I can do it here. 1 of them is a single curved line size 3579 × 715 and it's a 1,2 MB png very heavy. [**Here it is.**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X9JRR.jpg)

Comment: If the cropped images are cropped from a 100% size preview, then the lower image is clearly larger: the shapes are larger, the texture is enlarged etc.

Comment: "Here it is." -- no, that's a 42-kilobyte JPEG.  How about just running "pngcheck -v file.png" and see if that tells us anything useful, compared to the result of "pngcheck -v file.png" for the smaller one?

Comment: Is compression enabled on any of the images?

Answer (score 0):

you might have saved the first file as - "save for web" and the next file as normal "save as"......so that can make difference in file size.

Probably try saving the files as - **"save for web"** with **png-8** extension.

> Hope it was helpful

.

Comment: Thanks, but the 65% of my job is save images as png, 300dpi. So, I know what these means. Maybe I didn't explain myself very well (English isn't my born language). If I take any other png image and re-saved, this one is three or four times bigger. I've tried with my own images, net images, purchases, and everytime if I save it again, they are huge. Happens with new draw images too. This never happened to me before. The only change I did in the last days it was installing more RAM memory to my MAC, but this is not a reason for the problem. But thank you anyway.

Comment: ok....thn i guess its some other problem....i donno if this wil help, but u can try removing your cashe files and try again.....

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work :(